# Create string of keys from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this result of code:

```
[{'T': 0.9993631}, {'P': 0.998792}, {'D': 0.9962113}, {'F': 0.99601835}, {'C': 0.993832}]
```

I want to print result like this: TPDFC

I tried this for solution:

1):

```
import json
print(json.dumps(objects, indent=4))
```

but get this error:

TypeError: Object of type float32 is not JSON serializable

2):

```
for key in objects:
print(key, ' : ', objects[key])
```

but get this error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *generator expression* with `str.join()` to achieve this:

```
my_list = [{'T': 0.9993631}, {'P': 0.998792}, {'D': 0.9962113}, {'F': 0.99601835}, {'C': 0.993832}]

my_str = ''.join(list(d.keys())[0] for d in my_list)
# 'TPDFC'
```